# Problema al usar selenium con pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x

Hice un script muy simple con proxy autenticado usando selenium-wire. El script solo abre un sitio web para consultar la ip publica. El problema es que cuando uso el script ejecutandolo como script funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo convierto en un archivo ejecutable con pyinstaller el script ya no funciona.

El codigo que uso es este:

```
import time
from seleniumwire import webdriver


options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://tdt1RvAi59:VtSlkEIrJt@212.115.44.178:58542', 
        'https': 'https://tdt1RvAi59:VtSlkEIrJt@212.115.44.178:58542',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1' # excludes
    }
}


browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\t_t\\chromedriver.exe', seleniumwire_options=options)

browser.get('https://www.myip.com/')
```

Y el error que me aparece al ejecutarlo desdpues de convertiro a .exe con pyinstaller es este:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.webDriveExceptions: Message: unknow error: net:: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
   <session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88>
[79696] Failed to execute script test
```

Acaso pyinstaller arruina los script de selenium de alguna manera?